# Input string in char array C++

Tags: c++, user-input

This is my code:

```
char A[10];
char B[5];
cin >> setw(10) >> A;
cin >> setw(5) >> B;

cout << A;
cout << B;
```

If the input exceeds the array size (ex: 10 for `A` variable), then the program does not prompt me to enter the data for the second one. It goes right to the the end and execute the two "cout" lines.

Input: `abcabcabcabcabcabc` (for A)

Output: `abcabcabcabca` (13 space for char + 2 '\n')

Output expected:

`abcabcabc` (for A)
`dddd` (for B)

I want to enter data for both variables even if I entered too many characters for one of them

Comment: Why are you using `char[]` and `fgets` in C++?

Comment: What you describe sounds like C code. Use C++ things. For instance, `std::string` would be a good start.

Comment: should retag as C not C++

Comment: @Dorin try to improve your question by adding examples for (1) input, (2) actual output, and (3) expected output

Comment: "...the program jumps after the second variable"?

Comment: I use C++ to write this program and I have a struct with those variables : struct
      {
         char sFirstName[31];
         char sLastName[32];
         char sBirthdate[11];
         Gender theGender;
      } PersonalInfo; The question is what function can I use to input the data from keyboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you would do this more like as follows

```
std::string A,B;
std::getline(std::cin,A);
std::getline(std::cin,B);
```

This avoids any pitfalls with fixed-size arrays, such as `char[10]` and reads the full line. Alternatively, you may add a delimiter

```
const auto delim = '.'; // say
std::getline(std::cin,A,delim);
std::getline(std::cin,B,delim);
```

I don't think there is a simple way (i.e. not coding it yourself) for allowing multiple delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to read C strings with a fixed limit, the best approach is to use `fgets`, which is part of the standard C++ library.

You can also use `iomanip` to `setw`, like this:

```
char A[10];
char B[15];
cin >> setw(10) >> A;
cin >> setw(15) >> B;
```

Note that the length of the string that you get back will be less by one than the width that you set, because C strings require null termination.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2OZYv2)

**Note:** Although this mixture of C and C++ would work, you would be better off using `std::string` for an approach that is more idiomatic to C++. I recognize that this could be a learning exercise in which you are not allowed to use `std::string`, though.

Comment: `Note that the with is set to 1 less than the array size` - surprisingly this is not quite right: see [example at cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw#Example) or, [my fork of your demo](http://ideone.com/CsDdXc)

Comment: maybe the off-by-one note should be added to your `fgets` statement

Comment: @Wolf Doesn't the same logic apply to `fgets`? I think it treats the limit as the total size of the buffer, so when you pass 10 it reads 9 characters, and writes `'\0'` into the last character of the buffer.

Comment: [indeed!](http://ideone.com/T8yjQk) Wow! Then, the question is really about cutting the right amount of input from lines!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using C++, you can use `string`

```
string A,B;
cin>>A>>B;
```

Here you can scan as many characters as you want.

Comment: `as many characters as you want` - what if you want only 10 and 15 respectively?

Comment: @Wolf OP asked how to handle input overflow.

Comment: I was not able to translate this `when the input overcome entry` unequivocally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with C functions, you've got a couple of options.

The first option is to leverage the fact that `fgets` includes the newline in the string it reads, but only if the reason it stopped reading is because it hit the end of a line.  You can check whether the last character is a newline, and if not, throw out anything left in the input up to and including the next newline:

```
int count;

fgets(A, 10, stdin);
count = strlen(A);
if (count == 9 && A[8] != '\n') {
    do {} while (getc(stdin) != '\n');
}
fgets(B, 15, stdin);
printf("A: %s; B: %s\n", A, B);
```

If you don't want the newline in your string, be sure to remove it.  And you may want to treat too much input as an error rather than just skipping extra characters.

A slightly simpler option is to use `scanf` instead, but only if you don't want to allow spaces in each variable's input:

```
int count;

scanf("%9s%n", A, &count); 
if (count == 9) {
    do {} while (!isspace(getc(stdin)));
}
scanf("%14s", B);
printf("A: %s; B: %s\n", A, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

This C function reads a line of any length and returns a pointer to it in a newly allocated memory block (remember to `free()` it). If `keepNL` is true and a newline character (i.e. not EOF) stopped the reading, it's included at the end of the string. If `len` isn't `NULL`, `*len` is set to the length of the line, including any newline character. It makes it possible to read lines with `'\0'` in, which `strlen()` can't handle.

On failure, `NULL` is returned and `*len` is unchanged. If `feof()` is true, EOF was reached before any characters was read (no more lines in the file). If `ferror()` is true, an I/O error occured. If neither `feof()` nor `ferror()` is true, memory was exhausted.

Note that the memory block may be larger than the length of the string. If you need to conserve memory, `realloc()` it yourself to `*len + 1U`.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MIN_LINE_BUF ((size_t) 128U) /* >= 1 */

char *fgetline(size_t *len, FILE *stream, int keepNL) {
    char *buf;
    int c;
    size_t i, size;

    if (!(buf = malloc(size = MIN_LINE_BUF))) {
        return NULL;
    }
    i = 0U;
    while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n' || keepNL) {
            buf[i++] = (char) c;
            if (i == size) {
                char *newPtr;

                if (size > (size_t) -1 - size
                 || !(newPtr = realloc(buf, size <<= 1))) {
                    free(buf);
                    return NULL;
                }
                buf = newPtr;
            }
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ((c == EOF && i == 0U) || ferror(stream)) {
        free(buf);
        return NULL;
    }
    buf[i++] = '\0';
    if (len) {
        *len = i;
    }
    return buf;
}
```